# From Newtonian mechanics to Boltzmann (or statistical) mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium, ergodicity, boltzmann-equation

Classical mechanical systems observable on a dynamical scale are subject to Newton's laws. In this case, knowledge of the Hamiltonian allows us to minimize energy taking into account inertia. This allows us to calculate trajectories, find equilibria and derive many properties.

Classical mechanical systems consisting of large sets of particles are subject to Boltzmann's law. In this case, knowledge of the Hamiltonian allows us to minimize energy and maximize entropy. This allows us to calculate phase space weights and derive many properties.

Is it possible to proof that the two approaches are equivalent in some cases ? That is, proofing all assumptions made in micro-canonical and canonical formalisms based on Newtonian mechanics ? Or that the average properties generated by Newtonian trajectories are equivalent to Boltzmann average properties ? Or is it maybe possible to observe some kind of transition between the two cases if they are not equivalent ?

Comment: Boltzman *mechanics*??? I know of distributions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution in statistical mechanics.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this proof of the existence of thermodynamics for matter with Coulomb forces?: https://cmsr.rutgers.edu/images/people/lebowitz_joel/publications/jll.pub_61.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference. That only mentions the problem in the introduction without references or literature review, and then moves on to another topic.